IntelliSense reports that identifier "size_t" is undefined for standards > C++03
I use VS Code with Microsoft's C/C++ extension, which includes IntelliSense. Whenever I use size_t, it is not recognized by IntelliSense. I am aware that it isn’t a requirement in the C++ standard that size_t be defined and that using std::size_t may be more advisable. However, I am working on a project where I can not make such changes. Also, this usage is accepted by the compiler (clang-18).
Furthermore, I am confused that the error messages sports a C++20 tag, when my configuration sets the standard to C++17 (the same as used by the compiler).
IntelliSense message:

identifier “size_t” is undefined [C/C++(20)]

Minimal compiling example:
#include <cstddef>
int main() {
    size_t s = 0;
    return 0;
}

c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Operating system: openSUSE Tumbleweed

I tried playing around with the cppStandard parameter, since it seemed to be off already, and I found out that size_t would be correctly recognized for standards c++98 and c++03, and that the problem only appeared at standards c++11 and above. The compiler on the other hand accepts size_t for all standard settings. Has anything changed in the standard between these two versions?
So, the quick fix would be to simply set the configuration to c++03? Well, when the project uses CMake and a compile_commands.json file, this setting unfortunately has no more impact.
I would expect IntelliSense to recognize any type that the compiler in use deems valid. How can I get IntelliSense to accept size_t?
Edit:
I tried including <stddef.h>, but it did not help directly. I can notice that in "__stddef_size_t.h", the definition is grayed out with newer standards. From the comment in the source, I blindly tried adding compiler options which, didn't have any effect:
"compilerArgs": [
    "-Xclang",
    "-fno-builtin-headers-in-system-modules"
]

I read that IntelliSense may still have some issues with modules, since those are a recent addition. But I cannot understand why that happens for standards c++11 to c++17 as well. However, I now found out that changing the compiler to g++ does solve the issue.

size_t ≠ std::size_t.  You'd need to do a using std::size_t; first.

"I would expect IntelliSense to recognize any type that the compiler in use deems valid" - we would all like to expect that, but in reality that is not always the case. Many IntelliSense implementations use their own parser, so may (and often do) consider valid code, which a compiler accepts, as being invalid. So, never fully trust IntelliSense.  The compiler is the final source of truth.

Why can I use size_t and std::size_t in MSVS without the traditional headers?

What changes can you do? One solution would be to include <stddef.h> where size_t is  defined. Also it is odd that it seems to work for C++98, which specifically said that <cstddef> could not spill names into the global namespace. Later standards relaxed this.

@eljay I understand this. However, is there a way to tell this to IntelliSense without changing the source?
@bop I'm working on an open source project (Xournal++) where size_t is used widely and I would like to not need to make a change every time I come across a new file. I do not think it would be welcome to add std:: to all size_t either.
